# React single landing page with components

Tags: html, css, reactjs

Hello currently I'm making my portfolio and I'm using React framework to get things work.
I have 5 components that will be added in this single landing page. But when I'm adding another component/page it takes the space of the first page.

[image]

This is my first component which is called HomePage

```
const HomePage = () => {
const gradient = {
    backgroundImage: `linear-gradient(90deg, rgba(2,0,36,1) 0%, rgba(93,94,95,1) 0%, rgba(65,73,86,1) 58%)`,
    color: "white",
    fontSize: "16px",
    fontWeight: "bold",
};
const gradient2 = {
    backgroundImage: `linear-gradient(90deg, rgba(2,0,36,1) 0%, rgba(93,94,95,1) 0%, rgba(170,180,198,1) 50%)`,
    color: "black",
    fontSize: "16px",
    fontWeight: "bold",
};

return (
    <div className={"background1"}>
        <List>
            <ListItem disablePadding>
                <ListItemIcon>
                    <img src={SmallIcon} style={{ height: "50px" }} />
                </ListItemIcon>
                <ListItemText
                    primary={
                        <Typography
                            type="body2"
                            style={{
                                color: "#FFFFFF",
                                paddingTop: "1.5rem",
                                fontSize: "20px",
                            }}
                        >
                            WELCOME TO MY PORTFOLIO
                        </Typography>
                    }
                />
            </ListItem>
        </List>
        <div style={{ paddingTop: "2rem" }}>
            <Grid container spacing={2}>
                <Grid item xs>
                    <div style={{ textAlign: "center" }}>
                        <h1 style={{ color: "white", letterSpacing: ".3em" }}>
                            Sample <br /> NAME
                        </h1>
                        <p style={{ color: "gray" }}>
                            I am currently looking for a new role in a reputable <br />
                            organization that will utilize my diverse skills in UI/UX <br />{" "}
                            design and digital design.
                        </p>
                        <div style={{ textAlign: "center", padding: "1em" }}>
                            <Button style={gradient}>ABOUT ME</Button>
                            <span style={{ paddingLeft: "1em" }}></span>
                            <Button style={gradient2}>SEE DESIGN WORKS</Button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </Grid>
                <Grid item xs>
                    <div style={{ textAlign: "center" }}>
                        <img
                            // src={Genki}
                            alt="Remy Sharp"
                            style={{
                                height: "200px",
                                width: "200px",
                                border: "1px solid black",
                                borderRadius: "50%",
                            }}
                        />
                    </div>
                </Grid>
            </Grid>
        </div>
        <div style={{ paddingBottom: "1.5em" }}>
            <div style={{ textAlign: "center" }}>
                <div className={"footer1"}>
                    <Grid
                        container
                        spacing={{ xs: 2, md: 3 }}
                        columns={{ sm: 8, md: 12 }}
                    >
                        <Grid item xs={2} sm={4} md={4}>
                            <img
                                src="https://img.icons8.com/ios/50/ffffff/facebook-new.png"
                                style={{ verticalAlign: "middle" }}
                            />
                            <span style={{ color: "white" }}>facebook.com</span>
                        </Grid>
                        <Grid item xs={2} sm={4} md={4}>
                            <img
                                src="https://img.icons8.com/ios/50/ffffff/apple-mail.png"
                                style={{ verticalAlign: "middle" }}
                            />
                            <span style={{ color: "white" }}>sample@gmail.com</span>
                        </Grid>
                        <Grid item xs={2} sm={4} md={4}>
                            <img
                                src="https://img.icons8.com/ios/50/ffffff/instagram-new--v1.png"
                                style={{ verticalAlign: "middle" }}
                            />
                            <span style={{ color: "white" }}>instagram.com</span>
                        </Grid>
                    </Grid>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        {/* <AboutMe /> */}
    </div>
    );
};

export default HomePage;
```

and This is what happens when I uncomment the AboutMe component

[image]

This is my aboutme component

```
const AboutMe = () => {
return (
    <div className={"background2"}>
        <Grid container spacing={2}>
            <Grid item xs>
                <div
                    style={{
                        fontSize: "100px",
                        fontWeight: "bold",
                        color: "white",
                        textAlign: "center",
                        textShadow: "0px 70px #2a2a2a, 0px 140px gray",
                    }}
                >
                    ABOUT ME
                </div>
                <img
                    src={SVG1}
                    alt="hehe"
                    style={{ width: "100%", opacity: "95%" }}
                />
            </Grid>
            <Grid item xs>
                <div>
                    <p className={"itemCenter"}>
                        A goal-oriented and enthusiastic Bachelor of Science in
                        Information Technology graduate who has 4 years of professional
                        experience focused in IT technical support track. An artist
                        inclined to company branding designgs such as logos, clothing
                        prints, layouts, and website user-interface design. Designer of
                        Doughnut Clothing. A determined and critical-thinking team player
                        in e-sports. I am currently looking for a new role in a reputable
                        organization that will utilize my diverse skills in technical
                        support and digital design.
                    </p>
                </div>
            </Grid>
        </Grid>
    </div>


);
};

export default AboutMe;
```

And lastly this are my CSS

```
 * {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

#root {
    height: 100%;
}

body {
    margin: 0;
    font-family: "Poppins", sans-serif;
    -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
    -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
    height: 100%;
}

.background1 {
    /* min-height: 100%; */
    /* height: 100vh !important; */
    height: 100vh;
    width: 100vw;
    background-image: url("images/backgroundwithlogo.png");
    background-size: cover;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center center;
}

.footer1 {
    /* padding: 10px 10px 0px 10px;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 100%; */
    /* Height of the footer*/
    /* min-height: 50px;
    background: transparent; */
}

.background2 {
    /* min-height: 100%; */
    /* height: 100vh !important; */
    height: 100vh;
    width: 100vw;
    background-image: url("images/2.png");
    background-size: cover;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center center;
}
```

I'm having a hard time fixing this issue. I've searched everywhere but nothings working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is simple layout issue - you put `<AboutMe />` inside the `<div className={"background1"}></div>` element. Just put it outside

```
<>
  <div className={"background1"}>.....</div>
  <AboutMe />
</>
```